# How to trigger an event only on record creation and not on updation?

Tags: admin, event-observer, controllers, magento-1.8

I have a custom admin grid module. When I add an item to that grid it calls the saveAction() in the controller of my module (obviously).

I need to trigger a custom event after the record gets saved (like shown below).

```
public function saveAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('tendor')) {
    try {
            $tendor = $this->_initTendor();
            $tendor->addData($data);
            $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('products', -1);
            if ($products != -1) {
                $tendor->setProductsData(Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($products));
            }
            $tendor->save();
            // custom event to save vendor code
            $evtData = array('tendor_info' => $data, 'tendor_instance' => $tendor);
            Mage::dispatchEvent('my_custom_tendor_save_after', $evtData);
```

Now I want this event to be triggered only when a new record is added and not when the existing record is edited.

> How can I find the difference between creation of record and updation
>   of a record?

can someone help me in figuring this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this line in your controller:

```
$tendor = $this->_initTendor();
```

I can only assume that this takes the `id` parameter from `_GET` and loads the appropriate entity from the db.
You can add this line right below the line I mentioned:

```
$shouldDispatchEvent = !(bool)($tendor->getId());
```

`$shouldDispatchEvent` is true only if the `$tendor` object has an id.
Now wrap your `dispatchEvent` in this:

```
if ($shouldDispatchEvent){
    $evtData = array('tendor_info' => $data, 'tendor_instance' => $tendor);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('my_custom_tendor_save_after', $evtData);
}
```

**[EDIT]**.
An other way of doing it, in your case could be this:

```
if ($tendor->isObjectNew()){
    $evtData = array('tendor_info' => $data, 'tendor_instance' => $tendor);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('my_custom_tendor_save_after', $evtData);
}
```

This will work if your model extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` (and it should).
the member `_isObjectNew` is added to the model instance in the `_beforeSave` (see `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave()`) method, and since you want to dispatch your event after the save is done you should be able to access it.

Comment: You are too fast for me. I'll stop writing my answer now :-/

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. I still say you should add it. It will improve the answer ratio for this website and maybe you explain it better.

Comment: Thumbs Up for isObjectNew() !